# Custom option file download from Sales/Orders page in admin not working in Magento

Tags: magento, admin, magento-1.7

The link to the custom option file from the sales/order page in admin is: `index.php/admin/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/<my id>/key/<my key>`

The link to the same file from the website (NOT ADMIN), by accessing my account is: `index.php/default/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/<my id>/key/<my key>`

The same file has the above two links when accessing from admin or the website. However the link that is working is `index.php/default/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/<my id>/key/<my key>`

I.e. the one which has default in the link and not admin in the link.

Does anyone know how to get it working? What changes are needed? Also I am using Magento 1.7.

Comment: I have same issue in `magento 1.9.3.3` after upgrade. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was to use the base URL of the default store to generate the URL. 
Rewrite the following function in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php to below:

```
/**
 * Return URL for option file download
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getOptionDownloadUrl($route, $params)
{
    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
    $code = $websites[1]->getDefaultStore()->getCode();
    $params['_store'] = $code;

    return Mage::getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution in `magento 1.9.3.3` but not working any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer Its due to enable the “Add Store Code to Urls” in System -> Configuration -> General -> Web

Just Disable it. You Got an image to download in order.

Its working fine for single store site.

Comment: I tried your solution in magento 1.9.3.3 but not working any idea ?